# How can I find out what's happening behind the scenes - python arrays calculation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
np_mat = np.array([[1, 2],
               [3, 4],
               [5, 6]])
```

--we have 3x2 matrix here

```
np_mat + np.array([10, 10])
```

and result is below

```
array([[11, 12],
   [13, 14],
   [15, 16]])
```

what I know, when two matrices is being added x-y has to be the same.
what is [10,10] meaning here? how this calculation is happening behind the scenes?

to me: [10,10] acts like 3x2 matrix but it's not it's an array.

Comment: You may find out by changing [10, 10] to [10, 20]

Comment: Numpy Broadcasting: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: I understand [10,10] array is reshaped to be added in 3x2 array (matrix), thanks!

Comment: By the rules of broadcasting the original 2d 2 element array, with shape (2,) is treated as a 2d (1,2) array, and then as (3,2) to match the other.  Leading size 1 dimensions are added as needed, and then size 1 dimensions are scaled to match the other arrays.

Comment: Could you clarify what aspect you want explained? Many things are happening behind the scenes, but it is hard to know which would be helpful to you. My first guess was that you were asking about broadcasting, but are you asking about something else?

Comment: `np.array([10, 10])` is a 1d 2 element array.  `[10, 10]` is a 2 element list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people have mentioned in the comments, you are seeing NumPy's [**broadcasting**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) feature in action. I'm not aware of any better learning resources on the subject than the docs in that link — but probably there are some good videos on YouTube.

Your specific example is very similar to the one shown in Figure 1 in those docs linked to above.

I stopped to write this answer, because there is one way to perhaps get a sense of what is happening 'behind the scenes', and that's [`np.broadcast()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html). It produces a generator that hands back the pairs of numbers that the broadcasting step matches up. So, calling your arrays `x` and `y`, and changing one element of `y` to 11 so we can see things more easily, the broadcast result `b` is computed like so:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4],
              [5, 6]])

y = np.array([10, 11])
b = np.broadcast(x, y)
```

Now you can step over the pairs of numbers it is matching up:

```py
for u, v in b:
    print(u, v)
```

Resulting in:

```py
1 10
2 11
3 10
4 11
5 10
6 11
```

These pairs are then summed by the `+` operator and organized into the shape of the array with the larger number of dimensions, per the docs:

> The resulting array will have the same number of dimensions as the input array with the greatest number of dimensions.